# Hibernate inserting records in multiple table

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

My scenario is that i have three tables Template, Question and Choice.

here Template will have many questions and Questions will have many choices and Other field in Choice Table.

Im using single form in Struts2 to insert records. my Question is how to configure in hibernate???

Thanks !!!

```
@Entity
@Table(name="template")
public class Template {

@javax.persistence.Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="t_id")
private Integer Id;

private String temp;

@OneToMany(targetEntity=Question.class,  cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="tempId",  referencedColumnName="t_id")
private Set<Question> question;

//getter setter


 }

@Entity
@Table(name="question")
public class Question {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="Qid")
private Integer Qid;

private String question;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="tempid")
private Template template;

@OneToMany(targetEntity=Choice.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="qid", referencedColumnName="Qid")
private Set<Choice> choice;

//getter setter

}

@Entity
@Table(name="choice")
public class Choice {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer Id;

private String choice;

private String status;

private String description;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="qid")
private Question question;

//getter setter

}
```

************ controller*****************

```
public class UserController extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware{


HttpServletRequest request;

@Override
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request =request;
}

Dao dao = new Dao();


Template template = new Template();

Question question = new Question();

Choice choice = new Choice();


public Choice getChoice() {
    return choice;
}


public void setChoice(Choice choice) {
    this.choice = choice;
}


public Question getQuestion() {
    return question;
}


public void setQuestion(Question question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public Template getTemplate() {
    return template;
}


public void setTemplate(Template template) {
    this.template = template;
}

public String insert(){
    System.out.println(choice);
    SessionFactory sf = Dbutil.getConnection();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx =  session.beginTransaction();

    Choice ch1 = new Choice();
    ch1.setChoice(choice.getChoice());
    ch1.setStatus(choice.getStatus());
    ch1.setDescription(choice.getDescription());

    Set<Choice> chset =  new HashSet<Choice>();
    chset.add(choice);

    Set<Question> qns  = new HashSet<Question>();
    qns.add(question);

    Question q = new Question();
    q.setQuestion(question.getQuestion());
    q.setChoice(chset);

    Template t = new  Template();
    t.setTemplate(template.getTemplate());
    t.setQuestion(qns);

    dao.insertemplate(t,q, ch1);
    //session.save(t);
    //session.save(q);
    //session.save(ch1);

    tx.commit();
    session.flush();

    return "success";
}

}
```

*******************DAO******************

```
    public class Dao {


    public void insertemplateT(Template template, Question qn1, Choice ch1 ){

    SessionFactory sf = Dbutil.getConnection();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx =  session.beginTransaction();

    if(ch1!=null){
        insertChoice(ch1);
        if(qn1!=null){

            insertQuestion(qn1 );

            if(template !=null){
                session.save(template);
                tx.commit();
            }
        }
    }   

    }

    public void insertQuestion(Question qn1 ) {
    SessionFactory sf = Dbutil.getConnection();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx =  session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(qn1);
    tx.commit();
    }



    public void insertChoice(Choice ch1) {
    SessionFactory sf = Dbutil.getConnection();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx =  session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(ch1);
    tx.commit();
    System.out.println("committed");

    }



    }
```

***********sql show ************

> Hibernate: insert into choice (choice, description, qid, status) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
>   committed
>   Hibernate: insert into question (question, tempid) values (?, ?)
>   Hibernate: insert into choice (choice, description, qid, status) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
>   Hibernate: update choice set qid=? where Id=?
>   Hibernate: insert into template (temp) values (?)
>   Hibernate: insert into question (question, tempid) values (?, ?)
>   Hibernate: update question set tempId=? where Qid=?

******Question table image******
[image]

Comment: Use one to many mapping.

Comment: while using 1 to n im getting duplicate insertion in question table i dont know why?

Comment: Need to look at what you are trying.

Comment: Show how you inserting/updating your entities

Comment: @pomkine please check the code that i updated

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="template")
public class Template {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="t_id")
private Integer Id;

private String temp;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="template",  cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Question> questions;

}




@Entity
@Table(name="question")
public class Question {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="Qid")
private Integer Qid;

private String question;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="tempid")
private Template template;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="question", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Choice> choices;

public void addChoice(Choice choice){
    choices.add(choice);
    choice.setQuestion(this);
}

public void setTemplate(Template template){
    this.template = template;
    template.getQuestions.add(this);
}


@Entity
@Table(name="choice")
public class Choice {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer Id;

private String choice;

private String status;

private String description;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="qid")
private Question question;

}


Template template = //;
Choice choice = //;

Question question = new Question();
question.addChoice(choise);
question.setTemplate(template);

    public void insertQuestion(Question qn1) {
    SessionFactory sf = Dbutil.getConnection();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx =  session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(qn1);
    tx.commit();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Alan.. but its not working in the way what i expected. it doesnt insert any foreign key & again gives duplicate entry in question table

Comment: See updated. With the cascade options set and both sides of the relationship set you should be able to make one call to save Question and everything else should be saved.